# How to allow users to share their <modelname> with each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have User and Folder models, each user has his own folders (has_many/belongs_to). What I need to do is allow users to share some of their folders with each other, so shared folders become also their folders. I know, that I can just duplicate them, but I'm searching for less brute-force method.

I found [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-dropbox-like-file-sharing-site-with-ruby-on-rails--net-17940) and it's awesome, but too old - these methods don't work in Rails 4. What are the proper methods to re-write this code for Rails 4?

app/views/layout/application.html.erb

```
<head> 
  <title>ShareBox |<%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Untitled" %></title> 
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom" %> 
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.4.4.min", "jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min" %> 
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> 

<!-- This is for preventing CSRF attacks. -->
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.Rails" %> 


  <%= csrf_meta_tag %> 
  <%= yield(:head) %> 
</head>
```

app/views/home/index.html.erb

```
<div id="invitation_form" title="Invite others to share" style="display:none"> 
    <% form_tag '/home/share' do -%> 
            <label for="email_addresses">Enter recipient email addresses here</label><br /> 
            <%= text_field_tag 'email_addresses', "", :class => 'text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all'%> 
            <br /><br /> 
            <label for="message">Optional message</label><br /> 
            <%= text_area_tag 'message',"",  :class => 'text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all'%> 
            <%= hidden_field_tag "folder_id" %> 
    <% end -%>                 
</div>
```

Share link:

```
<%= link_to "Share", "#", :folder_id => folder.id, :folder_name => folder.name %>
```

assets/javascripts.js

```
$(function () {  
    //open the invitation form when a share button is clicked 
    $( ".share a" ) 
            .button() 
            .click(function() { 
                //assign this specific Share link element into a variable called "a" 
                var a = this; 

                //First, set the title of the Dialog box to display the folder name 
                $("#invitation_form").attr("title", "Share '" + $(a).attr("folder_name") + "' with others" ); 

                //a hack to display the different folder names correctly 
                $("#ui-dialog-title-invitation_form").text("Share '" + $(a).attr("folder_name") + "' with others");  

                //then put the folder_id of the Share link into the hidden field "folder_id" of the invite form 
                $("#folder_id").val($(a).attr("folder_id")); 

                //Add the dialog box loading here 
                $( "#invitation_form" ).dialog({ 
    height: 300, 
    width: 600, 
    modal: true, 
    buttons: { 
        //First button 
        "Share": function() { 
            //get the url to post the form data to 
            var post_url = $("#invitation_form form").attr("action"); 

            //serialize the form data and post it the url with ajax 
            $.post(post_url,$("#invitation_form form").serialize(), null, "script"); 

            return false; 
        }, 
        //Second button 
        Cancel: function() { 
            $( this ).dialog( "close" ); 
        } 
    }, 
    close: function() { 

    } 
});  
                return false; 
            }); 
});
```

With code above, clicking on Share link doesn't do anything. Dialog box doesn't appear. What should I change?

Answer (score 0):

Since multiple users can have the same folder, your first step to enable this should probably be to make the relationship between User and Folder many-to-many via an intermediate model. Something like:

```
class User
  has_many :shared_folders
  has_many :folders, through: :shared_folders
end

class Folder
  has_many :shared_folders
  has_many :users, through: :shared_folders
end

class SharedFolder
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :folder
end
```

How you implement the front end is up to you, but the form for creating a new `SharedFolder` will need to pass a `user_id` and a `folder_id` to the controller.

Comment: Of course that is exactly what I've dome - it is explained in the tutorial that I've linked. The problem is only with js form.